# Solr 5 restart losing cores

Tags: apache, solr, bitnami, solr5

Noob Solr question

I am trying to set up Solr, and to aid I have been using Apache Solr installer from bitnami.

This will install Solr 5.4.

I have gone and created a new core, and everything looks good. However when I restart solr, the core I have just created is lost.

I have not altered any configuration items from what is installed by Bitnami

I have been reading up about how Solr 5 is self discovering, and I am sure that everything is correct.

This is a copy of my solr.xml file from C:\Bitnami\solr-5.4.0-0\apache-solr\solr

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr>
  <solrcloud>
    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>
    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>
    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateSoTimeout">${distribUpdateSoTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateConnTimeout">${distribUpdateConnTimeout:60000}</int>
  </solrcloud>

  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:60000}</int>
  </shardHandlerFactory>
</solr>
```

And I have checked, and in the core folder I have created, there is a core.properties file in the the conf folder. This is the contents of the file

```
#Written by CorePropertiesLocator
#Tue Dec 22 10:37:24 UTC 2015
name=sitecore_analytics_index
config=solrconfig.xml
schema=schema.xml
dataDir=data
loadOnStartup=true
```

So I cannot understand why the core is not being discovered. Any help greatly appreciated

ps. I am doing this on Windows and not *nix